# Firebase real time updates for posts from people I follow

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get real time updates working with Firestore on my app. However, I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible in real time.

I have `Users` who follow other `Users`. When they post to the `Posts` collection, the users timeline should be updated in real time with the posts from users they follow. Is this possible?

I have an identifier `userId` on each post. Any help would be appreciated as I'm a bit stuck!

Comment: This is possible but *how* you do it is totally dependent on your Firebase structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch list of users that a user follows and

```
let queryRef = self.ref.child("posts/\(userID)")

queryRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        // new post from a friend 

    })
```

Comment: I'd have to use this method for every single person the user follows though which would be really slow!

Comment: fetch a small list of close friends (like facebook) , it doesn't necessary to be all , user will also click newS feeds and explicitly grab them all

Comment: While this kinda works, it's pretty limited because it assumes your structure is posts/userID, which is probably not the best structure for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a user john is logged In. First of all get userIDs of all the persons whom john is following. Store the userIDs in an array.

Than use an observer to listen for changes in the posts table. Whenever value of posts table is changed,

- check the userID of that post.
- if the array contains this userID. update the news feed of the logged In User.

Hope that helps.